# Resizing Qt UI elements

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple qt ui that contains

```
|- central widget
   |- label
   |- button
```

I would like to manually place and resize the label and button freely (using the mouse), and I just can't seem to be able to do that.

I can only resize the entire window, and the label/button stretch with it. I tried all combinations of size policies

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>326</width>
    <height>254</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Bla</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Start</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: You need to remove layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove
`<layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">`
and
`</layout>`
but if you are working under qt creator or qt designer,
you can easily do this thing. You need to choose centralWidget and click to button `Break Layout` that placed under menu bar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Break Layout did it

Answer (score 1):

Check [this documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-components.html). This should be helpful to utilize Qt Designer components. It is quite possible that you don't have to do lot of work. I never used this so my help ends here.